# What is the difference between 'kill' greenlet block or not

Tags: python, gevent, greenlets

when I am trying to kill a greenlet using kill(), a 'block' param is default by True,

```
Greenlet.kill(self, exception, block, timeout)
```

the doc says:

> If block is **True** (the default), wait until the greenlet dies or
>   the optional timeout expires.  If block is **False**, the current
>   greenlet is not unscheduled.

How to understand this properly? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say that you have two greenlets `A` and `B`.

1) Inside `B` you call `A.kill(block=True)`. Immediatly after that context switch happens, Python jumps to `A` and it raises an exception in `A`. `A` may handle it or not, it may jump somewhere else, timeout may occure on kill, etc.

2) Inside `B` you call `A.kill(block=False)`. Context switch **does not** happen. `B` continues to run other commands after kill. Kill command is scheduled to fire though, i.e. as soon as Python jumps to `A` it will raise the exception.

So AFAIK "block" simply means "do the switch now".